# Writing a generalized method to time any other method using Java 8 lambdas

Tags: lambda, java-8, timing

I've been trying to figure out if there's a way to write a method that takes a Java 8 method reference as an input,runs that method and returns the time it took to run.

```
public static long time(Runnable c) {
    long start, end;
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    c.run();
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return (end - start);
}
```

This is what I have so far, but this will only work for a method with no parameters...I'm looking for something that can work with a method that can take parameters as well. Is that possible?

Comment: As a side-note, if you intend to have this to do micro benchmarks then you'd be better off learning a benchmarking framework like JMH.

Comment: I really hope you're not planning to use this for benchmarking.

Comment: @BrianGoetz  Yes I do intend to use this for benchmarking. Could you explain what the problem with that would be?...

Comment: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/513259/2711488)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, a work around is to wrap your method inside a lambda

```
int foo =...
Object bar = ...

long elapsed = time( () -> myMethod(foo, bar));
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for